# Can I have feedback on my (elementary) proofs? I'm self-studying and have no one to look over my work.

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math

EDIT: I think these are good but I would love tips / detailed comments / places for improvement. I'm a high school graduate on a gap year and have no proof experience so I'm trying to show all my steps. How's phrasing?

1a) The average of real numbers $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ is given by $$M = \frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n}.$$ Show that at least one of the numbers $a_j$ satisfies $a_j \ge M$.

(a) Suppose (for the sake of contradiction) that there did not exist an $a_j$ that satisfied $a_j$ $\geq M$. Then, each $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ is strictly less than $M$. We can add the inequalities $a_1<M, a_2<M, \cdots ,a_n < M$ to obtain $$a_1 + \cdots + a_n < \underbrace{M + M + \cdots + M}_{\text{n copies}}$$ $$a_1 + \cdots + a_n < M*n$$ By substitution, we see that $$a_1 + \cdots + a_n < a_1 + \cdots + a_n $$ Since a sum cannot be strictly less than itself, this is a contradiction, and so I reject my initial assumption and conclude that at least one of the numbers $a_j$ satisfies $a_j$ $\geq M$.

(b) Arrange the numbers $1, \cdots, 9$ in a circle. Show that there must exist three adjacent numbers whose sum is at least $16$, no matter which circular arrangement you pick.

Consider an arbitrary arrangement of the integers $1, \cdots, 9$ in a circle.

[Circle of numbers a_1 to a_9]

Let $A = a_1+a_2+a_3$, $B = a_2+a_3+a_4$, $C = a_3+a_4+a_5, \cdots, I = a_9 + a_1 + a_2$. Since each $a_1, \cdots, a_9$ is in three groups, $A + \cdots + I = (a_1 + \cdots + a_9)*3 = 45*3=135$. The average of each group is $$\frac{A + \cdots + I}{9} = \frac{135}{9} = 15$$
By part (a), at least one of the groups $a_j$ satisfies $a_j \ge 15$. I will show that there exists an $a_j > 15$. Suppose to the contrary that there does not exist an $a_j > 15$. Then, to maintain the average, $A = B = C = \cdots = I = 15$. However, since $A=a_1+a_2+a_3=15=B=a_2+a_3+a_4$, then $a_1=a_4$, which is a contradiction, since $a_1$ and $a_4$ represent different integers from $1, \cdots, 9$. Thus, I reject my initial assumption and conclude that there exists an $a_j > 15$.

2. Consider a set of $n+1$ positive integers, each less than or equal to $2n$. Show there must always exist a pair of integers in the set, one dividing the other.

We use pigeonhole principle. For $1 \leq k \leq n$, let the $$k\text{th pigeonhole} = \{(2k-1)*2^t \mid t \text{ is a nonnegative integer, } (2k-1)*2^t \leq 2n\}$$ By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, every integer $n_i$ from $1,\cdots ,2n$ can be represented by $(2k-1)*2^t$, guaranteeing that every integer is in a pigeonhole. Since there are n pigeonholes and we must choose $n+1$ integers, there must be two integers, $i=(2k-1)*2^t$ and $j=(2k-1)*2^u$ for some k such that $i<j$, that are in the same pigeonhole. Thus, $i | j$ since $j=i*2^{u-t}$, where $u-t$ is a positive integer.

3. Suppose that five $1$s and four $0$s are arranged around a circle. Form a new circle by placing a $0$ between any two unequal adjacent numbers and a $1$ between any two equal values before then erasing the original values. Show that, no matter how many times you repeat this and no matter what the initial configuration is, you will never get a circle of all $0$s.

Suppose that you form a circle of all $0$s in $n$ steps. The only way to obtain a circle of $0$s is to have alternating numbers in step $n - 1$. However, this is impossible, since we have an odd number of $1$s and an even number of $0$s, meaning there must exist two adjacent numbers that are the same. Thus, we reject our assumption and conclude that we will never get a circle of all $0$s.

4. A guest at a party is a celebrity if this person is known by every other guest but knows none of them. There is at most one celebrity at a party -- if there were two, they would have to know each other, making neither a celebrity by the above definition. On the other hand, it is certainly possible that no guest is a celebrity. Devise a method for finding the celebrity at a party of $n$ people which involves only asking questions of the form ``Person $A$, do you know Person $B$?'' and which takes no more than $3(n-1)$ questions.

We use induction. Let $P(n)$ be the statement: "we can find the celebrity at a party of n people with no more than $3(n-1)$ questions." We will prove $P(1)$ and $P(n+1)$, assuming $P(n)$.
To see $P(1)$, we determine if this person is known by every other guest but knows none of them. Since there are no other guests, $P(1)$ holds vacuously.
To see $P(n+1)$ assuming $P(n)$, I choose two arbitrary guests and ask, "Person A, do you know Person B?". There are two cases to consider.
(1) If Person A knows Person B, then Person A is not a celebrity. Thus, we can momentarily remove Person A from the party to consider the sub-party of $n$ people without Person A. Using $P(n)$, we know we can find the celebrity, Person C, at the party with no more than $3(n-1)$ questions. If there is no celebrity, then we are done. If there is a celebrity, we now must determine whether Person C knows Person A and whether Person A knows Person C. If Person A knows Person C but Person C does not know Person A, then Person C is the celebrity for the original party of $n+1$ people. Else, there is no celebrity. (2) We follow the same reasoning if Person A does not know Person B, meaning Person B is not a celebrity.
Thus, in both cases,
\begin{align*} 
1 + 3(n-1) + 2 <= 3(n+1-1) \\
1+3n-3 +2 <= 3n \\
3n <=3n
\end{align*}
Thus, $\forall n \in \mathbb N, P(n)$ holds.

Comment: @saulspatz But m = (a_1 + ... + a_9)/(n), so can't I just substitute m in the expression a_1 + ... + a_n < nM

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: @saulspatz is that not clear from my proof? was phrasing ambiguous?

Comment: I wouldn't say, "We have by substitution,..." but would just display the calculation:  $$a_1+\cdots a_n<nM=n\frac{a_1+\cdots a_n}n=a_1+\cdots +a_n$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of it is excellent, but your solution to (3) isn’t quite right: you’ve not actually proved that at stage $n-1$ you will have an odd number of $1$s and an even number of $0$s. It’s possible to do so if you observe that in any circular arrangement of nine $0$s and $1$s there must be an even number of alternating blocks of $0$s and $1$s, so that at the next stage there must be an even number of $0$s and hence an odd number of $1$s. However, you don’t need to work even that hard: since $9$ is odd, you can never have alternating single $0$s and $1$s, so you can never get all $0$s.

Comment: Hi Professor, thank you for your input. So questions 1a/b,2, and 4 are all good? How's my updated proof: Suppose that you form a circle of 9 0s in n steps. The only way to obtain a circle of 0s is to have 9 alternating numbers in step n - 1. However, since 9 is odd, we can never have alternating 0s and 1s, and so there must exist two adjacent numbers that are the same. Thus, we reject our assumption and conclude that we will never get a circle of all 0s.

Comment: @beginner: Yes, the others were fine, though I agree with **saulspatz** that that one bit of 1(a) could be worded a little more clearly. And yes, your updated proof is fine.